# MYSQL date issue , unable to convert date

Tags: mysql

I have date `06-Jun-2014` and i want to convert it to `06/06/2014 00:00:00`

I tried this but not working...

`DATE_FORMAT('06-Jun-2014','%Y %m %d %T:%f')` => Returns NULL

`DATE_FORMAT(06-Jun-2014,'%Y %m %d %T:%f')` => #1054 - Unknown column 'Jun' in 'where clause'

Comment: That's not the format you are looking for. What does it return?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your string into a date first with [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).
Then convert that date into a string with [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select date_format(str_to_date('06-Jun-2014', '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/38826)

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your string into a `Date` first

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('06-Jun-2014','%d-%b-%Y'),'%m/%d/%Y %T')
```

**Output**

```
06/06/2014 00:00:00
```